# Custom search function for Select component

Tags: reactjs, search, antd

I am using ant design Select and Search component. I am using huge data set of 15k entries. I tried using "react-select-fast-filter-options" but the component is still freezing on Search. There are multiple solutions for the scroll problem like "infinite scrolling", pagination... But any idea how to solve the "Search" performance problem? like creating my own custom search function using high performance search algorithms? or should I just refer to the server to handle the search queries?

Comment: try use server side search for so big data.... no need upload all data to page and then filter it.

Comment: Second egorchik, this should be done server side. Just show the results client side.

Comment: And use autocomplete instead of simple select (antd). We're using it for database that has weight around 15TB !

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out in comments, this type of search should be performed with the help of backend code. Having thousands of select options will make the whole DOM slow, no matter what.

There are [bugs](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/5854) opened to AntD to improve performance of select, but I'm not sure this can be improved to handle 15000 items decently.

Also, add a [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#debounce) to your search box so that you just perform the search after user stops typing for a while (say 500ms), this should help with performance as well.

Comment: Well, I went for pagination from the server-side, I tried to do some sort of "infinite scroll" but unfortunately the AntD select does not track the location of scroll (it only provides onScroll option which fires each pixel). That was frustrating! I am trying to switch to a list component to do the virtualized and infinite loader trick now. I hope this works! For the search queries, I will definitely handle them  server side.